# Simple DispatchTimer Ticks are erratic WPF in Win10 only

Tags: wpf, timer, windows-7, windows-10

I have tried this on Win7 and Win10. On Win7 works as I thought, Tick is called every 100ms. But on win10, the Tick is called 2 times at run, and then stops until I do a mouseover the app, which fires anouther Tick for 1 time. This is weird.

I'm using System.Windows.Threading.

The code is all in code-behind to test it and this is all to keep it simple:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TimerGeneral(true);
        }

        public DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int s;

        public void TimerGeneral(bool estado)
        {
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);

            if (estado && !timer.IsEnabled) { timer.Tick += timer_Tick; timer.Start(); }

            else if (!estado && timer.IsEnabled) { timer.Stop(); }

        }

        public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("tick" + s++);
        }
    }
```

I'm a little lost why Win10 works different, sorry.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: I've read it several times before asking for help, thanks ;)

Comment: Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs. This is because DispatcherTimer operations are placed on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in the queue and their priorities

Comment: But why in Win7 it works but in win10 it doesn't, and if I compile it in Win7 and run the exe in win10, it works?  That's the reason I need to understand. Also, If I would like to use a Timer, how could I start I timer at a given time and receive Ticks as usual? Thanks.

Comment: Windows 10 has some mechanisms to  reduce CPU and Memory usage. In UWP apps there is a suspended state explicitly. When you compile against Windows 10 compiler adds injects platform specific optimizations. Did you try using `Timers.Timer`?

Comment: Timers.Timer is working, of course. But as my app has an UI, I thought I should use the Dispatcher to have every Thread synced. Maybe I didn't understand it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, that when instantiating `DispatcherTimer` using the default constructor (as you did), the timer's `Dispatcher` will by default execute with `DispatcherPriority.Background`! Hence the high latency.

Specify a higher priority by using the appropriate constructor:

```
var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, Application.Current.Dispatcher)
```

This should fix your issue.
In case the latency is still too high, try `DispatcherPriority.Send` (use with care).
If an operation is posted to a `Dispatcher` at `DispatcherPriority.Send`, the operation bypasses the queue and is immediately executed.

Depending on the timer interval and workload, the [`DispatcherPriority`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority?view=netframework-4.8#fields) should be as low as possible to prevent the UI from becoming sluggish.

Alternatively, if `Timers.Timer` or any other timer is working better for you, then just use it. You can execute the UI relevant code using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action)` or `Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Action)`.

Comment: The normal Priority works as expected. Thanks. I didn't know about this whole world of suspended mode in Win10 until this app, so something else learned. Great. Still a lot of stuff to learn :)